# German flour inside a sack

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> German flour inside a sack,
> I say, in poles‌, I can crack.
> **What am I?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Nutcracker

The word "poles" may be a reference to

> the two jaws of the nutcracker, which move like the poles of a lever to crack the nut.

Comment: What about 'German flour inside a sack' - how would this answer explain that part of the riddle?

Comment: The reference to "German flour" in the riddle may be a hint that nutcrackers are often associated with Germany

Comment: It was some obscure city, but I don't remember. I guess this works too!